# Having issue during installing Xgrafix on ubuntu (WSL2)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install Xgrafix on ubuntu using WSL2 on my system. i have successfully configured the Xgrafix using "sh run_conf.sh". Now proceeding to next step, when i enter the command `sudo make -j4` or `make j4` or simply `make`, i get the following error.

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:327: xtest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/work/mphil/xgrafix/ctest'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:358: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/work/mphil/xgrafix'
make: *** [Makefile:296: all] Error
```

Comment: Presumably `/mnt/d/work/` is a directory on the Windows (NTFS?) filesystem? often the issue is that the linker can't create executables on non-*nix filesystems. I'd suggest starting over with a working directory under your WSL/Ubuntu home directory.

Comment: I have also tried as you mentioned but getting same error.

Comment: Is the source code publicly available? if so please add a link

Comment: Yes, it is publicaly available. Here is the link

[Xgrafix](https://ptsg.egr.msu.edu/pub/codes/xgrafix.tar.gz)

Comment: You will have to edit the run_conf file to provide the directory for TCL and TK.

Here it is the edited version of [run_conf.sh](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rpcw6vBzCznWKVxG98cT0tBVFIExxVjP/view?usp=sharing) file